# How can I maintain state and "this" with react component functions

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Currently, when socket.io emits a 'gmessage' from my server, and the socket in my component catches it, my entire state is replaced.

So the current flow is like this:

I emit a message from the component, it goes to my server, then to the watson API. The API sends a response to my server, and the server sends that to the component.

So that first message creates the connection to socket.io, then the second socket.io event is caught on the same connection.

Is there a better way to set up the connection to socket.io and handle both the emit and the "on gmessage" parts of this? Thank you for **any** tips in advance. I'm still new to react, so anything you see that I should do differently is helpful!!

```
...
import {Launcher} from 'react-chat-window'
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import { getUser } from '../actions/userActions';

class Workshop extends Component {

  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        messageList: []
      };
    }

  _onMessageWasSent(message) {
    this.setState({
      messageList: [message, ...this.state.messageList]
    })

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

    socket.emit('message', { message });

    var myThis = this
    var myState = this.state

    socket.on('gmesssage', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      myThis.setState({
        messageList: [{
          author: 'them',
          type: 'text',
          data:  data
        }, ...myState.messageList]
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container className="DashboardPage" justify="center">
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <div>Welcome to your Workshop</div>
          <TeamsTaskLists />
        </Grid>

        <Launcher
          agentProfile={{
            teamName: 'Geppetto',
            imageUrl: 'https://geppetto.ai/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/geppetto-chat-avi.png'
          }}
          onMessageWasSent={this._onMessageWasSent.bind(this)}
          messageList={this.state.messageList}
          showEmoji
        />

      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = state => ({
  user: state.user
});

export default connect(
  mapStatetoProps,
  { getUser }
)(Workshop);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fareed has provided a working Redux solution and suggested improvements for a non-Redux approach, so I'd like to address the issues in your current code:

1. You're reinitializing the socket variable and creating its listener every time a new message is received instead of configuring and initializing the socket object just once inside a separate file and then consuming it by your Workshop component and possibly other components across your project.
2. You're appending the newly received message by calling `setState({ messages: [...] })` *twice* in **_onMessageWasSent**.

To solve the first issue, you can create a separate file and move your socket related imports and initialization to it like:

```js
// socket-helper.js

import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
```

Bear in mind, this is a minimal configuration, you can tweak your socket object before exporting it as much as the socket.io API allows you to.

---

Then, inside the Workshop component's **componentDidMount** subscribe to this socket object like:

```js
import { socket } from 'path/to/socket-helper.js';

class Workshop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ...
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // we subscribe to the imported socket object just once
        // by using arrow functions, no need to assign this to myThis
        socket.on('gmesssage', (data) => {
              this._onMessageWasSent(data);
        })  
    }

    ...
}
```

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) say

> If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

**componentDidMount** will run only once, so your listener will not get redefined multiple times.

---

To solve the second issue, **_onMessageWasSent** handler function should only receive the new message and append it to previous messages using setState, like this:

```js
_onMessageWasSent(data) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        messageList: [
            {
                author: 'them',
                type: 'text',
                data: data,
            }, 
            ...previousState.messageList,
        ]
    }))
}
```

Comment: That’s good answer but I guess you have 2 issues, first no need to have socket io client attached to the component you need only one client for your project

Comment: 2nd you don’t need to assign “this” to “myThis,  just use arrow function, arrow functions don’t have a this so “this” inside arrow function will be the component something like ‘this.socket.on(“gmessage”, () => { this._onMessageWasSent.... })

Comment: Correct. I assumed this is a basic practice project and all the logic will most likely be contained inside this Workshop class. I'll make an edit mentioning this. 
You're right on the other issue, too. I personally always use arrow functions in my code, but wanted to point out the mistakes to OP using his own coding style to avoid additional explanations, but I guess best practices should be enforced at all times.

Comment: I understand, but as you said it’s always better to force best practices especially his main issue related to the “this” keyword

Comment: I've edited my answer to init the socket in a separate file and just subscribe to it inside the component, it should've definitely been one of the main points of my answer. Appreciate the notes.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using redux it's better to make socket.io dispatch redux actions for you, you can use redux saga same as this [article](https://medium.com/@viacheslavlushchinskiy/real-time-data-with-redux-saga-event-channels-and-socket-io-ad6e64dbefd9) describes or you can use this implementation without saga but you need to have [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware :

1- Create a file lets say `lib/socket.js`

then inside this file create `socket.io` client lets call it `socket` and create `initSocketIO` function where you can fire any redux actions in response to socket.io:

```
 import socket_io from "socket.io-client"; 
 // our socket.io client
 export const socket = socket_io("http://localhost:5000");

 /**
 * init socket.io redux action 
 * @return {Function}
 */
export const initSocketIO = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // connect
  socket.on('connect', () => dispatch(appActions.socketConnected()));

  // disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', () => dispatch(appActions.socketDisconnected()));

  // message
  socket.on('message', message => {
      dispatch(conversationActions.addOrUpdateMessage(message.conversationId, message.id, message));
      socket.emit("message-read", {conversationId: message.conversationId});
  });

  // message
  socket.on('notifications', ({totalUnread, notification}) => {
    dispatch(recentActions.addOrUpdateNotification(notification));
    dispatch(recentActions.setTotalUnreadNotifications(totalUnread));
  });
};
```

2- then inside your `App` component call this action once your `App` is mounted:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {initSocketIO} from "./lib/socket.js";

export class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = configureStore();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // init socket io
    this.store.dispatch(initSocketIO());
  }
  // ... whatever
}
```

3- now you can also fire any socket.io action from any component using this:

```
  import React, {Component} from "react";
  import {socket} from "./lib/socket.js"

  MyComponent extends Components {
     myMethod = () => socket.emit("message",{text: "message"});
  }
```

or from any redux action using thunk for example:

```
  export const sendMessageAction = (text) => dispatch => {
     socket.emit("my message",{text});
     dispatch({type: "NEW_MESSAGE_SENT",payload:{text}});
  }
```

**Notes:**

1-This will perfectly work, but still, I prefer the redux-saga method for managing any side effects like API and socket.io.

2-In your components, you don't need to bind your component methods to `this` just use arrow functions for example:

```
myMethod = () => {
  // you can use "this" here
}

render = (){
  return <Launcher onMessageWasSent={this.myMethod} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application, I think Redux would be overkill for this.

I would change to a lambda expression here though to avoid having to save this references:

```
socket.on('gmesssage', data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.setState({
    messageList: [{
      author: 'them',
      type: 'text',
      data:  data
    }, ...this.messageList]
  })
})
```

You might consider using the new React Hooks also e.g. turn it into a stateless component and use `useState`:

```
const Workshop = () => {
    const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);
    ...
```